# Mega menu implementation with wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have to reproduce menu of the [winston.com](http://winston.com) website. It also has to work with wordpress, and I found the UberMenu but its sort of a personal project and I don`t want to spent money on plugins.

The website is built on bootstrap, and i found the next plugin: yamm 3 ( [website](https://github.com/geedmo/yamm3) ), but I simply cannot reproduce the menu from winston.com.

I also want it to be built on bootstrap, so if someone could help me make a reproduction with that YAMM3 plugin, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty basic, you should start with an on hover event. With this event just "show" the menu which is hidden at first. On this menu add a transaction effect http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Start of with a simple div that has the correct position after your menu items. Then try to implement a jquery/javascript function to show/hide the correct menu item. After that add a transaction effect. Keep it simple first, aka use some basic colors and widths to understand how this dropdown menu works. After that, just extend/improve it to make it look like your example.

Comment: I also want it to be built on bootstrap, so if someone could help me make a reproduction with that YAMM3 plugin, it would be better than building it from zero.